web.config - rewrite rule to change header value is not working
I want to change content-security-policy header by rewrite module in IIS.
Here is default CSP in customer header:
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders> 
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" 
             value="default-src 'none';script-src 'self';style-src 'self' ;img-src 'self' data:;font-src 'self';frame-src 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';connect-src 'self';object-src 'none';upgrade-insecure-requests;" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>

Here is rewrite value for Content-Security-Policy in rewrite tag:
<rewrite>
   <outboundRules>
      <rule name="Replace RESPONSE_Content_Security_Policy" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true"> 
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content-Security-Policy" pattern="*" />                 
          <action type="Rewrite" value="default-src 'none';" />
      </rule>                
   </outboundRules>   
</rewrite>

I use wildcard for pattern, and as you see, if I set pattern="*" (apply to all), it works like a charm! (replaced Content-Security-Policy header with value "default-src 'none';").
But when change to: pattern="\*viewfile\*", mean only apply for links like admin/invoice/viewfile?viewid=e9KwbLgmXSkyWhyOll, it doesn't work! It always uses customerHeader value as defined.
It seems like only work with * pattern?
I has try use a regular expression for pattern, but that did not work.
So, where did I go wrong?

Sorry everyone, I made a mistake in using the  tag and pattern above. Specifically, if used as shown, it applies to the value of the Content-Security-Policy  header, not the access link.

If you made mistakes, delete the question or revise it to the correct state.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Below setting works for me.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Set CSP for Viewfile" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*viewfile.*" />
            <action type="None" />
            <serverVariables>
              <set name="RESPONSE_Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'none';" />
            </serverVariables>
          </rule>

          <rule name="Default CSP" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <action type="None" />
            <serverVariables>
              <set name="RESPONSE_Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'none';script-src 'self';style-src 'self';img-src 'self' data:;font-src 'self';frame-src 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';connect-src 'self';object-src 'none';upgrade-insecure-requests;" />
            </serverVariables>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>

